# How to compare 2 QStringList's and show the results?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to know how can I compare 2 [`QStringList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QStringList.html) and display the results in the following way:

I have 2 [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPlainTextEdit.html) A and B

- In A I have, for example, 10 lines of 6 numbers per line;
- In B i have, for example, 100 lines of 6 numbers per line;

What I want to do is this: take each line in B and compare with all the lines in A. If, in one line-line comparison, all 6 are equal to int n6 (for example) will add 1. If only 5 are equal, the int n5 will add 1 and so on.

I've tried a few things but none of them worked. If you could give some light on this I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by calculating the number of matching digits per string

```
int matchingDigits(QString str1, QString str2)
{
    int matches = 0;
    int minSize = str1.size() < str2.size() ? str1.size() : srt2.size();
    for (int pos = 0; pos < minSize; ++pos)
    {
        if (str1.at(pos) == str2.at(pos) ++matches;
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Now you compare all a strings with each other (iterating over both StringLists) and if `matchingDigits()` is something `> 0` then you can increase your result counters.

```
QStringList listA;
QStringList listB;

foreach (QString a, listA)
{
    foreach (QString b, listB)
    {
        int matches = matchingDigits(a, b);
        if (matches > 0)
        {
            // do something fancy
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I forgot to say that this will be a lottery check app. Your method works but it returns 11 when 1;2;3;4;5;6 is against 1;2;3;4;5;6 (because of the ; I guess) and returns 3  when 1;2;3;4;5;6 against 23;53;46;60;13;24. How solve this?

Comment: Nevermind i got it. So how I can compare all strings with each other?

Comment: @Rafaelpsmed, I edited my answer to add a basic construction of the comparison. But is you have numbers > 9, the string comparison is not the best idea. You should first create a `QStringList` for each line, using http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#split

Answer (score 2):

Use `QSet` and `subtract()` and `count()` or `size()`

```
QStringList mOldList, mNewList;

  mOldList.append("1");
  mOldList.append("2");
  mOldList.append("3");
  mOldList.append("4");
  mOldList.append("5");
  mOldList.append("10");

  mNewList.append("1");
  mNewList.append("2");
  mNewList.append("3");
  mNewList.append("4");
  mNewList.append("5");
  mNewList.append("15");

QSet<QString> subtraction = mNewList.toSet().subtract(mOldList.toSet());
QSet<QString> subtraction1 = mOldList.toSet().subtract(mNewList.toSet());
foreach (const QString &filename, subtraction)
        qDebug() << " difference: "<<  filename;
foreach (const QString &filename, subtraction1)
        qDebug() << " difference: "<<  filename;
```

Result:

```
 difference:  "15" 
 difference:  "10"
```

For example with next lists:

```
  mOldList.append("1");
  mOldList.append("2");
  mOldList.append("3");
  mOldList.append("4");
  mOldList.append("5");
  mOldList.append("10");

  mNewList.append("1");
  mNewList.append("2");
  mNewList.append("3");
  mNewList.append("4");
  mNewList.append("5");
  mNewList.append("15");

QSet<QString> subtraction = mNewList.toSet().subtract(mOldList.toSet());
foreach (const QString &fileName, subtraction)
        qDebug() << " difference: "<<  fileName;
```

Result only 15:

```
 difference:  "15"
```

It means that one element is not same.

```
  mOldList.append("1");
  mOldList.append("2");
  mOldList.append("3");
  mOldList.append("4");
  mOldList.append("5");
  mOldList.append("10");

  mNewList.append("1");
  mNewList.append("2");
  mNewList.append("3");
  mNewList.append("4");
  mNewList.append("115");
  mNewList.append("15");
```

Two elements are not same:

```
 difference:  "115" 
 difference:  "15"
```

Or another way:

```
qSort(mNewList);
qSort(mOldList);

if(mNewList == mOldList){
    qDebug() << "same";
}
else{
    qDebug() << "not same";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but how i count this difference?

Comment: @Rafaelpsmed your  difference there is in QSet, so just call count() method for substraction. It returns you number of elements in QSet, but it is a number which you are looking for.

Comment: thanks it worked. but how i compare the first line in QPlainText B with all the lines in QPlainText A? and then compare the second line in B with all the lines in A and so on?