# How to properly compare Q_ENUM and QStringList

Tags: c++11, qt5, qtablewidget, qstring, qenum

I have a small example `.ui` where the user can drag and drop from a `QListWidget` to a `QGraphicsView` using `QGraphicsProxyWidget` a specific widget (in my case is a `QTableWidget`) as shown below.

**Basically the behavior I have been looking for is:**

If I drag and drop "Imgaes" than the `QTableWidget` on the `QGraphicsView` will have 2 columns and 2 rows; (which is correct)
If I drag and drop "Path" than the `QTableWidget` on the `QGraphicsView` will have 3 columns and 3 rows; (which is wrong)

[image: pr1]

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVuea.jpg

Below the selection of "Path", which still give 2 rows and 2 columns instead of 3 rows and 3 columns

[image: pr2]

[2] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLRSx.jpg

Below the code:

**scene.h**

```
class Scene : public QGraphicsScene {

    enum LaserTableWidget {
      Images,
      Path
    };
    Q_ENUM(LaserTableWidget)

public:
  Scene(QObject *parent = nullptr);

  void compare(const QString& comp);

  template<typename QEnum>
  std::string QtEnumToString (const QEnum value)
  {
    return std::string(QMetaEnum::fromType<QEnum>().valueToKey(value));
  }

protected:
  void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
```

**scene.cpp**

```
Scene::Scene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent) {
    setBackgroundBrush(Qt::lightGray);
}

void Scene::compare(const QString &comp)
{
    // get information about the enum named "LaserTableWidget"
    QMetaObject MetaObject = this->staticMetaObject;
    QMetaEnum MetaEnum = MetaObject.enumerator(MetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("LaserTableWidget"));
    QStringList tabs;

    switch (MetaEnum.keyToValue(comp.toUpper().toLatin1()))
    // or simply switch (MetaEnum.keyToValue(word)) if no string modification is needed
    {
        case Images:
        for (const QString &color : tabs) {
            QPoint initPos(0,0);

            QTableWidget *wgt = new QTableWidget;
            QGraphicsRectItem *proxyControl = addRect(initPos.x(), initPos.y(), wgt->width(), 20, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::darkGreen)); // widget->width() works properly here because of the resize(layout->sizeHint()) that we have used inside it
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

            wgt->setColumnCount(2);
            wgt->setRowCount(2);
            for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < wgt->rowCount() ; ridx++ )
            {
                for (int cidx = 0 ; cidx < wgt->columnCount() ; cidx++)
                {
                    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
                    item->setText(QString("%1").arg(ridx));
                    wgt->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);
                }
            }
            QGraphicsProxyWidget * const proxy = addWidget(wgt);
            // In my case the rectangular graphics item is supposed to be above my widget so the position of the widget is shifted along the Y axis based on the height of the rectangle of that graphics item
            proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y()+proxyControl->rect().height());
            proxy->setParentItem(proxyControl);
        }

        break;
        case Path:
        for (const QString &color : tabs) {
            QPoint initPos(0,0);

            QTableWidget *wgt = new QTableWidget;
            QGraphicsRectItem *proxyControl = addRect(initPos.x(), initPos.y(), wgt->width(), 20, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::darkGreen)); // widget->width() works properly here because of the resize(layout->sizeHint()) that we have used inside it
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

            wgt->setColumnCount(3);
            wgt->setRowCount(3);
            for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < wgt->rowCount() ; ridx++ )
            {
                for (int cidx = 0 ; cidx < wgt->columnCount() ; cidx++)
                {
                    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
                    item->setText(QString("%1").arg(ridx));
                    wgt->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);
                }
            }
            QGraphicsProxyWidget * const proxy = addWidget(wgt);
            // In my case the rectangular graphics item is supposed to be above my widget so the position of the widget is shifted along the Y axis based on the height of the rectangle of that graphics item
            proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y()+proxyControl->rect().height());
            proxy->setParentItem(proxyControl);
        }
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}


void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) {

  QByteArray encoded =
      event->mimeData()->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
  QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

  QStringList rosTables;

  while (!stream.atEnd()) {
    int row, col;
    QMap<int, QVariant> roleDataMap;
    stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;
    rosTables << roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
  }

  compare(const QString &comp)
}
```

I tried to use the `template` function declared on the header file that for completeness I am also attaching below:

```
  template<typename QEnum>
  std::string QtEnumToString (const QEnum value)
  {
    return std::string(QMetaEnum::fromType<QEnum>().valueToKey(value));
  }
```

Maybe I the template function is the wrong choice? I was trying to find a way to use it if possible.

That is the reason why I switched to a `void compare(const QString& comp);` function and tried to delegate the job to a `switch - case` statement but that also is not working as I expect and I still see the same exact `QtableWidget` dropped onto the `QGraphicsView`.

Of course I did more research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317994/how-to-compare-2-qstringlists-and-show-the-results) source and above all [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281682/how-to-convert-enum-to-qstring) which was useful to understand the basic comparison and following this post I decided to go ahead and try to apply the `Q_ENUM - QString` or even the `QStringList` as a valuable tool. But I could not figure out what I was doing wrong.

Can anyone please shed light on which approach could be better? (or maybe they are both correct) and try to explain what I am missing to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think that the given code can even produce the wrong output. `tabs` is just an empty list, then for each element in `tabs`, a table is displayed?

Comment: I assume `comp` to be "Images" or "Path", why is `toUpper()` used?

Comment: Hello @NgocMinhNguyen and thanks for stopping by and reading the question. Yes `comp` is used for either "Images" or "Path". The problem I have is that I was trying to combine that with using the `template<typename QEnum>` function. It is a way for me to practice using `template<>` compared with `QEnum` and `QString` but something is missing and can't figure out what could that be.

Comment: You haven't answer my questions

Comment: Sorry you are right :) ok so: 1) yes for each element in `tabs` a table is displayed. 2) I was using `toUpper()` in a way to make the darg-drop from `QListWidget` choices (e.g. "Images", "Path") to `QGraphicsView` as case sensitive. So if there is "images" instead of "Images" the `MetaEnum` should throw and error and therefore the `template<typename QEnum>` shoud be able to handle that.

Comment: 1) But `tabs` is an empty list, the loops are not entered. 2) Since there is no "IMAGE" and "PATH" in your enum, the call to `keyToValue()` should always return -1

Comment: Could you please answer with some code so that I am able to better understand your suggestion? :) Thank you very much so far for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I see in your code:

1. Wrong parameter passed to `keyToValue()`. Since you have `Image` and `Path` in your enum, the valid values to pass to `keyToValue()` are "Image" (returns 0), and "Path" (return 1), other values will returns -1.
2. In the function `Scene::compare()`, `tabs` is just created as an empty `QStringList`, so the code inside the loops `for (const QString &color : tabs)` are never executed

Below is a test program to show you what I mean:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMetaEnum>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    enum LaserTableWidget
    {
        Images,
        Path
    };
    Q_ENUM(LaserTableWidget)

    template<typename enum_type>
    QString QtEnumToString (const enum_type value)
    {
        return QMetaEnum::fromType<enum_type>().valueToKey(value);
    }
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // First problem: wrong parameter passed to keyToValue()

    qDebug() << 1 << QtEnumToString<LaserTableWidget>(Images);
    qDebug() << 2 << QtEnumToString<LaserTableWidget>(Path);

    QMetaObject MetaObject = this->staticMetaObject;
    QMetaEnum MetaEnum = MetaObject.enumerator(MetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("LaserTableWidget"));

    qDebug() << 3 << MetaEnum.keyToValue(QtEnumToString<LaserTableWidget>(Path).toUpper().toLatin1());
    qDebug() << 4 << MetaEnum.keyToValue(QtEnumToString<LaserTableWidget>(Path).toStdString().c_str());

    switch (MetaEnum.keyToValue(QtEnumToString<LaserTableWidget>(Path).toUpper().toLatin1()))
    {
        case Images:
            qDebug() << "switch Images";
            break;
        case Path:
            qDebug() << "switch Path";
            break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "switch default";
            break;
    }

    // Second problem: tabs is empty
    QStringList tabs;
    for (const QString &color : tabs)
        qDebug() << color; // this line is never executed
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

Output:

```
1 "Images"
2 "Path"
3 -1
4 1
switch default
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. I understand now what you mean with the `Q_ENUM` and how to correctly use it. Your time is greatly appreciated :) . Also if you think my question was clear please give me a thumbs up :)